# variation on a standard Caesar-cipher

Tags: cipher

This is a slight variation on a standard Caesar-cipher:

```
cttgmqi ivy jnznas kki bim nrcnf ty qj lwamqdwo mau iei uy dlgk ppgzgobhz 
rrp ipt uyjum af xq cctmuhz vcgt pxit rfz oom yc uus lsw xbmxp di whk 
llteig cjna i oftp goqx ppn gnr swhsk yd vcqhlowpry ubfs owhs lssl mq iig 
zgk lpald rw ohlanrp x ao bpi sftp hhfx qxb hyccv walw kp qea hlcg iwime e 
ggtwhl es dlryr pdx qe fjm mzc jnei kykog g ipdshlc vj lsgv jot rfzq xbbe
```

What is the message? *(Spaces left in so not too cryptic!)*

*If off-topic, please comment & I will remove.*

Comment: I think it's completely on-topic c:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution:

> oranges and lemons say the bells of st clements you owe me five farthings say the bells of stmartins when will you pay me say the bells of old bailey when i grow rich say the bells of shoreditch when will that be say the bells of stepney i do not know says the great bell of bow here comes a candle to light you to bed and here comes a chopper to chop off your head

Explanation:

> The shift for the current letter is always the index of the previous letter in the standard latin alphabet. If there is no previous letter, the shift is 12. (Still trying to figure out why) So in other words, it's a vigenere cipher with the key
>  *`"o" + encryptedText`*

Comment: Why does it start with "c" and not "O"?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Oh wow... It amazes me how I missed that. I have to figure that out quickly :(( *panics*

Comment: @JonathanAllan Because an "o" was used instead of an "a"